# What is the difference between the representation of a group and an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Sometimes, I come across the following idea in physics.

The representation of Lorentz group: $SO(3,1)$ and the representation of Lorentz algebra: $so(3,1)$.

At times, I mix them up. Is there a good intuitive way (instead of going back to look it up) which I can always keep in mind in order to distinguish between the two?

Comment: It is the difference between a group homomorphism, and a (Lie) algebra homomorphism. If you see Lie brackets $[x,y]$, then you know its about Lie algebra representations.

Answer (score 4):

A representation of a $\color{Blue}{\sf group}$ $G$ is a $\color{Blue}{\sf group}$ homomorphism $G\to{\rm GL}(V)$.

A representation of a $\color{Green}{\sf lie~algebra}$ $\frak g$ is a $\color{Green}{\sf lie~algebra}$ homomorphism ${\frak g}\to{\frak gl}(V)$.

Note if you see actions added together or see lie brackets, it's a lie algebra repesentation.

Comment: please define $V$. Can you give an example of the first statement? Can you give an example of the second statement.